# How to paramerterize variables in docker-compose file that can run with and without env file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-registry

I am new to docker .I recently came across one of the docker-compose file from our org ACR, the ports are defined as variables in the compose file. I DO NOT have the docker file of that image used in docker-compose file.

```
version: "3"
services:
    webapp:
        image: p32d1830151.azurecr.io/web/weblogic:0.1
        container_name: banker
        hostname: banker
        ports:
          - "${URL_PORT}:8080"
          - "${TCP_PORT}:12345"
```

The advantage of this docker-compose.yml file is that

1. It can be executed with docker-compose up -d . The default value is taken
2. It can be executed with docker-compose --env-file d.env up -d , that overrides the default value with the values from env file.

I tried to do achieve the same with my docker images that is different from the same , and it fails with error

```
 docker-compose up -d
WARNING: The URL_PORT variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The TCP_PORT variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.webimage.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
services.webimage.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
```

but it works if I define the port as

```
    ports:
      - "URL_PORT:8080"
      - "TCP_PORT:12345"
```

or

```
    ports:
      - "URL_PORT:${URL_PORT}"
      - "TCP_PORT:${TCP_PORT}"
```

1. Has               - "${URL_PORT}:8080"
   - "${TCP_PORT}:12345" for any...?  if so please let me know how to make this work ?
2. Should something be added to the docker file ?
3. Do we have some documentation on this ?
4. How do I attain this flexibility ?

Answer (score 1):

> 1 How does this work ?

Notice that `${}` or single a `$` substitutes environment variables inside the `docker-compose.yml`.
This means when you've set an environment variable like `URL_PORT` docker-compose will replace `$URL_PORT` with its value.

Setting the environemnt variable can be done by running `export URL_PORT=1234` before you do `docker-compose up -d` or by placing a `.env`-file containing `URL_PORT=1234` in the current directory.

> 2 Should something be added to the docker file ?

No you don't have to add anything to the `Dockerfile`

> 3 Do we have some documentation on this ?

See: [Environment variables in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)

> 4 How do I attain this flexibility ?

By setting environment variables.

Comment: @dnltineey, the question was how to get         ports:
          - "${URL_PORT}:8080"
          - "${TCP_PORT}:12345" and documentation sorrounding it . the documentation that you have send is rather a generic one